# Problem with JavaScript AES 256 decryption of data that is encrypted in C

Tags: javascript, c, encryption, aes

When I do **AES-256 CTR** encryption in **C** using **tiny-AES-c** library (https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) I unable to decrypt it properly in JavaScript. 
For JavaScript decryption I'm using library https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js

After encryption I do base 64 encode and before decryption base 64 decode and that part works fine.

In fields below you can see my C and JavaScript code:

**C code**

```c
// AES start
struct AES_ctx ctx;
uint8_t enc_buf[32];
uint8_t iv[16] = 
    {0xf0,0xf1,0xf2,0xf3,0xf4,0xf5,0xf6,0xf7,0xf8,0xf9,0xfa,0xfb,0xfc,0xfd,0xfe,0xff};
uint8_t key[32] = 
    {0x60,0x3d,0xeb,0x10,0x15,0xca,0x71,0xbe,0x2b,0x73,0xae,0xf0,0x85,0x7d,0x77,0x81,0x1f,0x35,0x2c,0x07,0x3b,0x61,0x08,0xd7,0x2d,0x98,0x10,0xa3,0x09,0x14,0xdf,0xf4};
uint8_t test_str[32] = { 0, };
uint8_t test_str_size = 32;

AES_init_ctx_iv(&ctx, key, iv);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < test_str_size; i++) {
    test_str[i] = 'A';
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < test_str_size / 32; i++) {
    memcpy(enc_buf, test_str + i * 32, 32);
    AES_CTR_xcrypt_buffer(&ctx, enc_buf, 32);
}
// AES end
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var key = [96,61,235,16,21,202,113,190,43,115,174,240,133,125,119,129,31,53,44,7,59,97,8,215,45,152,16,163,9,20,223,244];

var encryptedBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(ascii_to_hexa(parsedStr));
var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(key, new aesjs.Counter(240));
var decrypted = aesCtr.decrypt(encryptedBytes);
console.log('%c AES decrypted: ', 'color: blue', decrypted.toString());
```

I'm unable to decrypt original data.

Does anyone can help me with this problem? Is there any libraries that is known to be compatible between C and JavaScript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question is missing a question, and an error description.

Comment: tiny-AES-c uses 128 bit encryption by default. Have you changed that for it to be 256 bit? Also you need to pass your IV as an argument to aesjs.Counter.

Comment: Yes, I've changed encryption to 256 in tiny-AES-c library and verified with online EAS256 encryption. I've put the right IV as argument to aesjs (as you can see it is 31, just like in C code) but with no luck on getting the same result as from tiny-AES-c. Is IV set ok in my code comparing to C? Did you manage to do it or have some example? Thanks.

Comment: @Embedded you need to pass entire IV array to aesjs.Counter as initial value. It expects either a number (which I don't know why is 31 in your case) or a 16-byte array. In case of a number all leading bytes are just set to zeroes.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub  Sorry I didn't put code with right value for IV. Now I've edited it. It is set to 240 (f0) like from the C code. Is that OK? Please, tell me what IV I should set in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @Embedded I've posted the working code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass entire IV as initial counter value:

```js
var key = [0x60,0x3d,0xeb,0x10,0x15,0xca,0x71,0xbe,0x2b,0x73,0xae,0xf0,0x85,0x7d,0x77,0x81,0x1f,0x35,0x2c,0x07,0x3b,0x61,0x08,0xd7,0x2d,0x98,0x10,0xa3,0x09,0x14,0xdf,0xf4];
var iv = [0xf0,0xf1,0xf2,0xf3,0xf4,0xf5,0xf6,0xf7,0xf8,0xf9,0xfa,0xfb,0xfc,0xfd,0xfe,0xff];
var parsedStr = '4a9e3cb0185657721fdbca54892184431b2f28dc122058471572c77dce243ad5';

var encryptedBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(parsedStr);
var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(key, iv);
var decrypted = aesCtr.decrypt(encryptedBytes);
console.log('%c AES decrypted: ', 'color: blue', decrypted.toString());
```

Output:

```
[Log]  AES decrypted:  – "65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65,65" (_display, line 40)
```

Note that it would automatically create `aesjs.Counter` from the given value if you don't pass an object of `aesjs.Counter` type. It is equivalent to passing `new aesjs.Counter(iv)`.

Also note you shouldn't reuse IV for CTR mode. It is supposed to be a random nonce for each packet, so no known plaintext attack is possible.

Comment: Yeeeaaaaah!!  THANKS A LOT!! U saved me.

Comment: Please see if you can help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59923424/compatible-lzw-compression-decompression-libraries-in-c-and-javascript-that-are

Comment: @Embedded sorry, I have no idea. JS libraries are not my forte.